# Misaligned .dem from Civil 3D into ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, civil3d

Imported 3 .dem files from a Civil 3D file. The two surfaces(topographic maps) fit correctly into my ArcMap file but the third surface, a bathymetric contour, seems to be misaligned and the scaled too big. I already tried checking the projections and units are all the same both in Civil 3D and in ArcMap. I also tried importing the files individually into a blank map but the third surface really won’t fit.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: for now I've just georeferenced the bathymetric surface into the other surfaces and it seems to be sufficient for my project but I was hoping to get a more exact answer if possible since the georeferencing is based on how precise I'm able to place the similar points and since the contours are different, it isn't really exact.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to change Dem format? Change Dem to geotiff in civil3d tehn import to arcmap. sometimes changing formats, changes some odd errors and problems.

Comment: I just tried it but it still gave the same result when I imported the file into ArcMap